# What is a "hash function generator"

Tags: hash

I heard/read this term many times, but cannot understand it. The name implies it should "generate a hash function" and I naively imagine it generating a source code in C for example. I looked on web search, here on Stackoverflow, looked into Wikipedia. But cannot find no good definition and no examples.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function):

> A **perfect hash function** for a set S is a hash function that maps
>   distinct elements in S to a set of integers, with no collisions. A
>   perfect hash function has many of the same applications as other hash
>   functions, but with the advantage that no collision resolution has to
>   be implemented.

If you know your keys in advance, you can construct such a perfect hash function. Programs that do so are called **perfect hash function generators**.

One example is [GNU gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/), which works like you suggested, taking in a list of keys and printing out C source code.

Answer (score 2):

A hash function generator is a tool for finding a hash function meeting certain criteria. Its output can be in any form that unambiguously describes the hash function, usually in the form of source code in some programming language.

### Examples

#### Perfect hash function

Given a set of distinct strings (for example {"banana", "peach", "pineapple", "apple", "microsoft", "pinemicrosoft"}), find a hash function that will map them to distinct integer values. For example:

```
"banana"        => 6
"peach"         => 2
"pineapple"     => 123
"apple"         => 3
"microsoft"     => 77
"pinemicrosoft" => 451
```

There is no restriction on what the hash function may return for an input string that doesn't belong to our predefined set.

#### Minimal perfect hash function

Similar to above, but the hash values must form a contiguous range.

```
"banana"        => 1
"peach"         => 2
"pineapple"     => 3
"apple"         => 4
"microsoft"     => 5
"pinemicrosoft" => 6
```

The simplest implementation meeting the functional requirements for a minimal perfect hash function is

- to store internally a sorted array of the target strings,
- look-up the input value in that array and
- return its index.

The drawbacks of such an implementation are that it consumes storage and slows down as the size of the target input set grows. So an additional requirement on the hash function is to minimize its size and running time.

#### Classificator

Given a set of distinct strings grouped into non-overlapping subsets, find a hash function that will map each string to the index of the subset it belongs to.

For example:

```
any of {"banana", "peach", "apple"}      => 1 // fruit
any of {"lion", "zebra", "dog", "eagle"} => 2 // animal
any of {"red", "green", "blue", "white"} => 3 // color
```